# SBT package to include only a few external jars but not all

Tags: scala

Is there a way that I can use sbt package to include a few external jars but not all. I am aware about sbt assembly but that will include all the jars that is configured in build.sbt

Comment: I am not entirely sure what do you mean, but you can use `Compile` dependencies for things that should be added to JAR and `Provided` for things that are assumed to be already present where the build JAR will be used.

Comment: Do you mean to exclude transitive dependencies? https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies

Answer (score 2):

In that case you have to give the dependencies without "provided" option and add "provided" to exclude the dependencies for packages in build.sbt file.

Example: 
Here I have given "provided" for spark-streaming dependency, which will not be included in my fat jar:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
```

But pureconfig dependency package which will be included in my fat jar as I have not mentioned the "provided" keyword:

```
"com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.12.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `assemblyExcludedJar` setting in the assembly plugin. There's an example in the sbt-assembly README:

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := { 
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {_.data.getName == "compile-0.1.0.jar"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/my.jar")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).